# PDF to CSV - converted CSV has interchanged contents of the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tabula-py

I am trying to convert a PDF file into CSV using Python and the below code. Earlier it was working; however, recently it is not working. I am getting interchanged column contents in the converted CSV file.

Guide me to fix this column issue in my code. I am only concerned about the first page of the PDF conversion as I need to remove the first rows of the table.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tabula
import pandas as pd
import csv

pdf_file='/pdf2xls/Input.pdf'
column_names=['Product','Batch No','Machin No','Time','Date','Drum/Bag No','Tare Wt.kg','Gross Wt.kg',
              'Net Wt.kg','Blender','Remarks','Operator']

# Page 1 processing
df1 = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages=1,area=(95,20, 800, 840),columns=[93,180,220,252,310,315,333,367,
                                                                      410,450,480,520]
                     ,pandas_options={'header': None}) #(top,left,bottom,right)

df1[0]=df1[0].drop(columns=5)
df1[0].columns=column_names
#df1[0].head(2)

#df1[0].to_csv('result.csv')

result = pd.DataFrame(df1[0]) # concate both the pages and then write to CSV
result.to_csv("/pdf2xls/Input.csv")
```

Comment: Please take relevant portion of PDF file and add to the question and show us expected output and what you got as output.

Comment: Can you explain why you removed the PDF link from the question? All details should be in the question itself, not hidden in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your pdf have always at least two pages with a footer in the last one, you can try :

```
# pip install pdfplumber
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

pdf = pdfplumber.open("23JJ0WL139.pdf")

tables = []
for p in pdf.pages:
    ta = p.extract_tables()[0]
    if str(p) == "<Page:1>":
        header = ta[4]
        tables.append(pd.DataFrame(ta[5:]))
    else:
        tables.append(pd.DataFrame(ta))
                    
df = pd.concat(tables).iloc[:-3].set_axis(header, axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   Product    Batch No Machin\nNo  ... Net\nWt.kg Blender Operator
0    GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.40            Anand
1    GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.60            Anand
2    GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.20            Anand
3    GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.20            Anand
4    GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.80            Anand
..     ...         ...        ...  ...        ...     ...      ...
11   GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.60            RAHUL
12   GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.60            RAHUL
13   GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.80            RAHUL
14   GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.40            RAHUL
15   GC950  23JJ0WL139     WB_101  ...      51.80            RAHUL

[140 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: PDF file can be of any number. What I am doing is if PDF file is single page then user script-page1 and if it has multiple pages then split it, convert it and then concatenate it. How can I use your code to support this method.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the issue with your code is related to column interchange in the converted CSV file. This problem could be caused by the way you are specifying columns when using `tabula.read_pdf`. You can modify the column coordinates to ensure that each column is correctly identified and extracted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tabula
import pandas as pd

pdf_file = '/pdf2xls/Input.pdf'
column_names = ['Product', 'Batch No', 'Machin No', 'Time', 'Date', 'Drum/Bag No', 'Tare Wt.kg', 'Gross Wt.kg',
               'Net Wt.kg', 'Blender', 'Remarks', 'Operator']

# Page 1 processing
df1 = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages=1, area=(95, 20, 800, 840), columns=[93, 180, 220, 252, 310, 355, 380, 410,
                                                                     450, 480, 520], pandas_options={'header': None})

df1[0].columns = column_names
df1[0] = df1[0].drop(0)  # Remove the first row
result = pd.DataFrame(df1[0])
result.to_csv("/pdf2xls/Input.csv", index=False)  # Set index=False to avoid writing the index column
```

In this modified code:

1. I've adjusted the column coordinates in the `columns` parameter to ensure that each column is correctly identified.
2. I've removed the first row using `df1[0] = df1[0].drop(0)` to get rid of the header row.
3. I added `index=False` when saving the DataFrame to CSV to prevent the index from being written as a separate column.

Comment: @jorgi Dri The given code is working for single page PDF however when I tried for the shared 3 page PDF, the output is with interchanged columns

Comment: The shared script is not working for multiple pages of PDf file. the output is still interchange in between the columns. Please check and guide me.